# .Net Regex to extract text

Tags: .net, regex

Hi I have a lot of html files and I need to extract some information from it, for example, to extract the device model number, I use the regex code below:

```
string sFullString = "Device:</span> <span id=\"model-value\" category=\"model\">DXE-9880</span></li>";
        string sStart = "category=\"model\">";
        string sEnd = "<";
        Regex regex = new Regex("(?<=" + Regex.Escape(sStart) + @").*(?=" + Regex.Escape(sEnd) + @")", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        Match match = regex.Match(sFullString);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
        }
```

The expected result would be "DXE-9880", but it's always "DXE-9880</span>". 
Why is the 2nd "<" picked up after the model number, not the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just make the inbetween `.*` to `.*?` because `.*` is greedy which matches all the chars as much as possible.

```
Regex regex = new Regex("(?<=" + Regex.Escape(sStart) + @").*?(?=" + Regex.Escape(sEnd) + @")", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

**OR**

Use a negated char class.

```
Regex regex = new Regex("(?<=" + Regex.Escape(sStart) + @")[^<>]*(?=" + Regex.Escape(sEnd) + @")", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

`[^<>]*` matches any character but not of `<` or `>`, zero or more times.